# ruby не удаляет нечетный элемент масива

Tags: массивы, ruby

Есть массив числ, хочу четные элементы из одного массива перекинуть в другой.
Есть код:

```rb
numbers=[3,543,25,6,753,96,100,53,50]
newlist=[]
newlist=numbers
newlist.each do |numb|
  ind=newlist.index(numb)
  if numb.odd?
    newlist.delete_at(ind)
  end
end
puts newlist
```

При выводе второго массива будут числа:
543
6
96
100
50

Вопрос: как здесь оказалось число 543?

Comment: ответ не касается задания, но алгоритмически ваш код неверен, т.к проще не удалять элемент из 2 массива если он нечетный, а наоборот добавлять во второй если он четный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, зачем вы используете `each` и тут же получаете
индекс?  Вы понимаете, что вы сами себе *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* из
ничего сделали?

Во-вторых, *никогда*, повторяю, **никогда** не
удаляйте элементы из итератора, по которому проходитесь.  У вас же мясо
получится:

```
Iteration start:
  3  543  25  6  753  96  100  53  50
  ^

First element deleted:
  543  25  6  753  96  100  53  50
  ^

Second iteration:
  543  25  6  753  96  100  53  50
       ^
```

Понимаете, в чём дело?  Элементы сдвигаются, но итератор об этом ничего
не знает.

Answer (score 3):

Зачем такие сложности? Есть же готовый метод `filter`

```
numbers = [3, 543, 25, 6, 753, 96, 100, 53, 50]
even_numbers = numbers.filter(&:even?)
```